# Scraping a React page with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage made in React with BeautifulSoup, but I keep getting the same problem: When I get the webpage back it only renders a page that says `You need to enable Javascript to run this app`.

This is the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--enable-javascript")
browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver", chrome_options=options)
browser.get('webpagehere')
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

I've tried multiple alternatives, including response_html and requests.get but I still keep getting the same result. Is there any way I can fix this? I'm using Python 3.9

Comment: What's the url? Can't replicate your issue code without it.

Comment: https://mycompumed.com

Comment: The page seems to have that inside a noscript tag. What is the expected output?

Comment: For that url it should return a login page